# Graphite. Some metrics lost, but seen in tcpdump

Tags: graphite

I'm using graphite for pretty long time, and first time facing issue with some metrics getting… lost?
Through `tcpdump -nA dst port 2003` I can see that metrics are delivered to Graphite node. 
Also, some of them are getting created in whisper database, and seen in `/var/log/carbon/updates.log`
But most of them are not appearing anywhere.

**So my question is:** how do I debug it? How do I prove that Graphite really receives these metrics from eth0?

I couldn't find any debug logs except for `updates.log` in carbon.

**Log:**

```
sudo tcpdump -An dst port 2003 | grep 172_31_00_01 | grep requests
```

> backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.max 60554.34 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mean 16714.87 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.min 2.93 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.stddev 12185.74 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p50 16415.87 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p75 20314.51 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p95 41526.36 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p98 54370.59 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p99 60368.68 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.p999 60553.31 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.count 3141 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.m1_rate 2.02 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.m5_rate 1.95 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.m15_rate 1.20 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mean_rate 0.66 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.max 152.59 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.mean 41.86 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.min 0.82 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.stddev 24.84 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.p75 57.51 1453734067
>   backend.dev.172_31_00_01.requests.mark_sessionid_active.p95 85.78 1453734067

```
$ pwd
/var/lib/graphite/whisper/backend/dev/172_31_00_01/requests
$ ls -Rl
.:
total 1796
drwxr-xr-x 2 _graphite _graphite    4096 Jan 25 14:25 mark_sessionid_active
-rw-r--r-- 1 _graphite _graphite 1831744 Jan 25 15:05 mean.wsp

./mark_sessionid_active:
total 3584
-rw-r--r-- 1 _graphite _graphite 1831744 Jan 25 15:05 min.wsp
-rw-r--r-- 1 _graphite _graphite 1831744 Jan 25 15:05 stddev.wsp
```

**PS:** It's not new installation, it works for several months now, and no metrics was lost until today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `MAX_CREATES` setting in `carbon.conf`. Setting it to high value (like 1000) or `inf` solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `LOG_DIR` variable in `carbon.conf`. In my case it's `/var/log/carbon/` and I can see a lot of logs in there like `console.log`, `creates.log`, `listener.log`. I believe `creates.log` is the one you are after.

If the `.wsp` file is created but you cannot see it in Graphite directly, try trying to render it anyhow using the URL API and see if it works.