# No metrics in Graphite

Tags: graphite, grafana, collectd

I have been at this for eight hours now, and nothing seems to work. I am not receiving any metrics in my Graphite installation. I am using [Grafana](http://grafana.org/) to display the data, and it works like a charm, only that the data from Graphite is empty.

Response:

```
[]
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and as far as I understand, Collectd can send the data properly to Carbon as I get the following when I restart Collectd:

`/var/log/carbon/listener.log`

```
11/02/2016 22:47:45 :: MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:51926 closed cleanly  
11/02/2016 22:47:47 :: MetricLineReceiver connection with 127.0.0.1:51927 established
```

I am running a VPS on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Where can I start troubleshooting? Grafana works and Collectd works, as far as I can tell, but Graphite refuses to show any metrics.

Thank you.

Comment: Try sending metrics directly to Graphite (carbon): http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html#the-plaintext-protocol

Comment: Thanks for your comment, dukebody. Unfortunately, I don't understand the documentation at all. I'm not sending data manually, which seems to be the only thing documented. I'm still using Collectd, which I can only configure to connect to Graphite through carbon, which apparently works. What should I change?

Comment: I understand you're not sending data manually, but I think you should test each "connection", testing first if data sent manually to Graphite shows up in the dashboard. You can also try to render the metrics you just sent using the URL API: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html   Also see this about Graphite log debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35172951/356729

Comment: Alright, I tried this now, and I get nothing in my logs; not in any of the carbon logs and nothing in the dashboard. I'm running all three services (graphite, collectd and grafana) on the same server, and I've tried all local IPs. Where should I start looking?

Comment: Check that carbon is running and listening on the port you are sending the packets to.

Comment: The listener log indicates the connection opening and closing, but you may also want to use WireShark (on the Ubuntu machine) to confirm that Collectd is actually sending data over that connection.  (It's easy to set WireShark to filter packet capture to only the sender IP or only the destination port so you don't have to sort through all your network traffic.)